# Merging the datasets into one single column by using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, merge

looks like I need your help, I am trying to merge the datasets into a single dataset. By using this codes

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
Total_Transfer = pd.read_excel('total_transfer.xlsx')
Total_Issued = pd.read_excel('total_issued.xlsx')
Total_Retirement = pd.read_excel('retirement_finalist.xlsx')
pd.merge(Total_Issued,Total_Retirement,Total_Transfer, on ='Vintage')
```

However it shows an error like this

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-053aa3dcdb13> in <module>
----> 1 pd.merge(Total_Issued,Total_Retirement,Total_Transfer, on ='Vintage')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py in merge(left, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, copy, indicator, validate)
     87         validate=validate,
     88     )
---> 89     return op.get_result()
     90 
     91 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py in get_result(self)
    666             self.left, self.right = self._indicator_pre_merge(self.left, self.right)
    667 
--> 668         join_index, left_indexer, right_indexer = self._get_join_info()
    669 
    670         llabels, rlabels = _items_overlap_with_suffix(

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py in _get_join_info(self)
    882             )
    883         else:
--> 884             (left_indexer, right_indexer) = self._get_join_indexers()
    885 
    886             if self.right_index:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py in _get_join_indexers(self)
    860     def _get_join_indexers(self):
    861         """ return the join indexers """
--> 862         return _get_join_indexers(
    863             self.left_join_keys, self.right_join_keys, sort=self.sort, how=self.how
    864         )

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py in _get_join_indexers(left_keys, right_keys, sort, how, **kwargs)
   1326         for n in range(len(left_keys))
   1327     )
-> 1328     zipped = zip(*mapped)
   1329     llab, rlab, shape = [list(x) for x in zipped]
   1330 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py in <genexpr>(.0)
   1323     # get left & right join labels and num. of levels at each location
   1324     mapped = (
-> 1325         _factorize_keys(left_keys[n], right_keys[n], sort=sort, how=how)
   1326         for n in range(len(left_keys))
   1327     )

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py in _factorize_keys(lk, rk, sort, how)
   1993         count += 1
   1994 
-> 1995     if how == "right":
   1996         return rlab, llab, count
   1997     return llab, rlab, count

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1327 
   1328     def __nonzero__(self):
-> 1329         raise ValueError(
   1330             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1331             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I don't understand where the ambiguity comes, but I am sure that I have change the data type in to numeric for the key value of every datasets.

I am very appreciate for your support on this one. Thanks!

Comment: welcome to SO. please read on https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Comment: please provide some minimal samples to reproduce. you can do that by `Total_Transfer.loc[:20].to_dict()`

Comment: Strange error.  My first guess and total guess would be maybe one of your dataframes has two columns with the name of "Vintage".  Would you please show what Total_Issued.columns and Total_Retirement.columns returns?

Comment: Hi Scott, here it is :
Total_Issued.columns
Index(['Unnamed: 0', 'Project ID', 'Vintage', 'Quantity'], dtype='object')
Total_Retirement.columns
Index(['Unnamed: 0', 'Project ID', 'Vintage', 'Quantity'], dtype='object')

Nope, there is only one column named Vintage in each dataset. Please let me know what you think

Comment: Hi @srinath, Here is the result :

`{'Unnamed: 0': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3},
 'Project ID': {0: 10, 1: 10, 2: 82, 3: 82},
 'Unnamed: 2': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 73, 3: 73},
 'Project Name': {0: 0.12019587896457373,
  1: 0.9595857671694371,
  2: 0.9068528595978774,
  3: 0.22956248183410222},
 'Vintage': {0: 2011, 1: 2012, 2: 2004, 3: 2011},
 'Quantity of Units': {0: 505.13940353702804,
  1: 488.6637557077407,
  2: 552.599517980261,
  3: 793.0871101004223}}`

I make it short as I don't understand how to put the code in the comment. Really appreciate for your help on this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this error appears because you are not using correctly pandas merge() function - you can merge only two DataFrames at a time.

Maybe it helps:

```
Total_Issued.merge(Total_Retirement, on ='Vintage').merge(Total_Transfer, on='Vintage')
```

or

```
pd.merge(pd.merge(Total_Issued, Total_Retirement, on = 'Vintage'), Total_Transfer, on='Vintage')
```

Comment: Hi MaryRa, Thanks a lot for your help, what should I do if I used two different "key value" for this format? for this case, I use "Project ID" and "Vintage" to merge the datasets. Thanks!

Comment: If I understand correctly, do you mean something like this? `Total_Issued.merge(Total_Retirement, on =['Vintage', "Project ID"]).merge(Total_Transfer, on=['Vintage', "Project ID"])`

Comment: And without deleting the NAN value in every column when merging it.

Comment: Hi MaryRa, seems like this works from my side! Thanks, but it seems like the code deletes the NAN value that appears in each row. Do you have any idea how to keep the NAN value available? So later on, I can change the NAN value into a numeric value.

Comment: It would be better if you can add pictures of you DataFrames to the question above. Because about NAN values there can be different reasons why they are deleted.
For example if you want to merge all three tables by 'Vintage' column, it's very important to remember that it's inner join by default. It means that all three tables must contain at least one Nan value in this column in order to have Nan value in the result table, otherwise it will be deleted.

Comment: Thanks! I understand now, I just realize that the lengths of every dataset are different which causes some of the rows to be missing. And eventually, I used left join to this so there are no values missing. Thanks again for your insight!!